# Communication between two hosts with closed ports

Tags: python, networking, port, broadcast

I'm struggling with implementing a LAN communication between two devices. I dont want to open any ports on each side. The communication will be to exchange some data.

With two devices in same LAN network, creating a communication is not a problem when one side opens port.
The problem arises when I wish to provide minimum open ports between hosts, but I don't really think there is a easy way to do it.
I was thinking about using broadcast domain as a communication channel, so device HOST1 sends encrypted message to broadcast address, and HOST2 listens to broadcast and decrypts the message.

The downsize of this is, all devices within LAN will receive the message, thus putting some(?) overhead to the network.

Are there any other methods I can use except the broadcast one?

```
from socket import *
cs = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
cs.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
cs.sendto('This is a test', ('255.255.255.255', 54545))
```

Comment: What is the problem with opening ports?

Comment: I don't want to open any ports on any side. This project will work only in LAN, but I want to force maximum security.

Comment: I don’t think ports is a security solution. Perhaps ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python

Comment: @RedS yeah, that's not really how the LAN and security works. If you tell your OS to listen for any kind of information, it's going to listen for it. About the only thing that it does is eliminates the possibility of nabbing the session, but when you have two hosts spewing a ton of UDP packets you can pretty much tell who's talking to who.

Comment: You may want to have a look at hole punching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)